# Is there any command for maven similar to “dotnet add package xxx”?

Tags: java, maven, .net-core

I'm a .NET developer who is new to java development. In the .NET world, we use a simple command `dotnet add package xxx` to add a dependency. I would like to know  if there are any similar commands for maven to add dependency?

Comment: By "add dependency", do you mean modifying the POM to include an additional dependency?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- yes!

Comment: As far as I know there is none, even though the most popular java editors (such as IntelliJ or Eclipse) offer shortcuts that produce the same result. But the command line version does not exist. What is however possible is to locally install a dependency using ```mvn install:install-file```

Comment: @alainlompoa  shortcuts? Could you  provide even more detailed information on these shorcuts? I`m using vscode as my primary java editor

Comment: @alainlompo This will not modify the pom file

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, exactly, the pom has to be manually modified or using an Ide such as INtellij, there are sortcuts such as ```alt + enter``` that does it foryou. @Blue Steel, I did not use Vscode much with maven unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java world, With maven there is such a command that changes pom.xml on the fly.
Instead you're expected to open up the pom.xml file in your favorite editor and add a dependency section:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
 <artifactId>some.artifact.id</artifactId>
 <version>some.version</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you might consider re-importing the pom.xml in the IDE (or configure the IDE to automatically re-parse the pom once its changed).

Of course if you're working with a maven directly (like want to add a dependency and immediately compile it) - you can just type `mvn compile` and it will download the dependency automatically if its still not in a local cache under the hood, so this command will compile the code with a new dependency in a classpath already.

Comment: The answer that @NareshKumar has provided does a different thing: It installs the artifact of the dependency that cannot be downloaded from the maven repository to the local filesystem. It doesn't modify the pom.xml of the project.

Comment: Note that the major IDEs have autocomplete tools for inserting these dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, but using the POM directly is probably a better way.

```
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId="group-id" \
   -DartifactId="artifact-id" -Dversion="version" -Dpackaging="packaging"
```

Adding jar file in local repository example [here](https://www.java2novice.com/issues/add-jar-into-mvn-local-repository-command-line/).

Maven guideline [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Comment: It is only for adding jar in local repository. It will not modify the pom.xml file